# Random Enemy movement in facing direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make my enemy ships simulate actual spaceships. So the ships accelerate forward but over-time move in a different direction as displayed in the image attached. This needs to be a random direction to face but it must transition smoothly to the next direction to stop this jittering effecting I have with my current method.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5fnV.jpg

I'm currently trying to do the code I have shown but it makes the enemy object flicker between each rotation and its not smooth.

```
    public float directionChangeTimer = 5f;

    public float accelerateSpeed;

    public void addRandomDirection()
    {
        float randomAngleAdd = Random.Range(-5f, 5f);

        transform.Rotate(0, 0, randomAngleAdd);
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        //Add our Functions
        addRandomDirection();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you rotate between `-5` and `5` degree **each frame**.

If you want this to be smoother you could use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) like e.g.

```
public float directionChangeTimer = 5f;

public float anglesPerSecond = 1f;

public float accelerateSpeed;

private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(RandomRotations);
}

private void IEnumerator RandomRotations()
{
    while(true)
    {
        // wait for directionChangeTimer seconds
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(directionChangeTimer);

        // get currentRotation
        var startRot = transform.rotation;

        // pick the next random angle
        var randomAngleAdd = Random.Range(-5f, 5f);

        // store already rotated angle
        var alreadyRotated = 0f;

        // over time add the rotation
        do
        {
            // prevent overshooting
            var addRotation = Mathf.Min(Mathf.Abs(randomAngleAdd) - alreadyRotated, Time.deltaTime * anglesPerSecond);

            // rotate a bit in the given direction
            transform.Rotate(0, 0, addRotation * Mathf.Sign(randomAngleAdd));

            alreadyRotated += addRotation;

            yield return null;
        }
        while(alreadyRotated < Mathf.Abs(randomAngleAdd));
    }
}
```